# How to refer to a specific key in IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase>

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I wanted to know how to refer to a specific element/key with in a web page based on the name of the input.

I have a form as below and I would like to upload three images into a SQL-Express database:

```
else if (property.PropertyName == "Image1")
                    {
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="file1">Filename:</label>
                            <input type="file" name="fileUpload[0]" />
                            @if (Model.Image1 == null)
                            {
                                <div class="form-control-static">No Image</div>
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                <div> Image</div>
                            }
                        </div>
                    }
                    else if (property.PropertyName == "Image2")
                    {
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="file2">Filename:</label>
                            <input type="file" name="fileUpload[1]" />
                            @if (Model.Image2 == null)
                            {
                                <div class="form-control-static">No Image</div>
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                <div> Image</div>
                            }
                        </div>
                    }
                    else if (property.PropertyName == "Image3")
                    {
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="file3">Filename:</label>
                            <input type="file" name="fileUpload[2]" />
                            @if (Model.Image3 == null)
                            {
                                <div class="form-control-static">No Image</div>
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                <div> Image</div>
                            }
                        </div>
                    }
```

My controller is the below:

```
[HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Edit(Client client, IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase> fileUpload)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            if(fileUpload != null)
            {
                foreach (var file in fileUpload)
                {
                    //if (file.ContentType == "jpg")
                    //{

                        if (file.FileName == "fileUpload[0]")
                        {
                            client.Image1 = new byte[file.ContentLength];
                            file.InputStream.Read(client.Image1, 0, file.ContentLength);
                        }
                        if (file.FileName == "fileUpload[1]")
                        {
                            client.Image2 = new byte[file.ContentLength];
                            file.InputStream.Read(client.Image2, 0, file.ContentLength);
                        }

                        if (file.FileName == "fileUpload[2]")
                        {
                            client.Image3 = new byte[file.ContentLength];
                            file.InputStream.Read(client.Image3, 0, file.ContentLength);
                        }
                    //}
                }
            }               
            Repo.SaveProduct(client);//this is an interface to save the changes to the database.

            return RedirectToAction("Index");
```

How do I map back to a particular variable in the Enumerable, I'm using this file.FileName == "fileUpload[2]". I'm fairly certain that it is what's wrong. I'm trying to refer to the html tag ''. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: `file.FileName` returns the name of the file that the user uploaded (not the name of the property). Its unclear what you wanting to do here.

Answer (score 0):

Convert to a list and use the index

```
if(fileUpload != null) {
    var files = fileUpload.ToList();
    for (var index = 0; index < files.Count; index++) {
        var file = files[index];

        if (index == 0) {
            client.Image1 = new byte[file.ContentLength];
            file.InputStream.Read(client.Image1, 0, file.ContentLength);
        }

        if (index == 1) {
            client.Image2 = new byte[file.ContentLength];
            file.InputStream.Read(client.Image2, 0, file.ContentLength);
        }

        if (index == 2) {
            client.Image3 = new byte[file.ContentLength];
            file.InputStream.Read(client.Image3, 0, file.ContentLength);
        }                   

    }
}
```